# How to prove two binomial expressions are equivalent?

Tags: summation, binomial-coefficients

I have two binomial expression: $S1= \sum_{k=0}^{\frac{n}{2}}{{n}\choose{2k}} $ and $ S2 =\sum_{k=0}^{\frac{n-1}{2}}{{n}\choose{2k + 1}} $. I have to prove those two expression are equal, and then find their shared value.

So far I'm trying to find a telescoping sum such as S1-S2=0 but can't do it.I'm probably missing something.

Answer (score 1):

Hint

For natural number $n,$

$$(1+x)^n+(1-x)^n=?$$

$$(1+x)^n-(1-x)^n=?$$

Then set $x=1$

Comment: This is what I get: $(1+x)^n + (1-x)^n = \sum_{k=0}^{n}{{{n}\choose{k}} (x^k +(-x)^k)}$ and  $(1+x)^n - (1-x)^n = \sum_{k=0}^{n}{{{n}\choose{k}} (x^k -(-x)^k)}$. Am I right ?

Comment: @Corentin, use binomial expansion

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
\begin{align}
&\left\{\begin{array}{rccclcl}
\ds{S_{1}} & \ds{\equiv} &
\ds{\sum_{k = 0}^{\left\lfloor n/\pars{2k}\right\rfloor}{n \choose 2k}}
& \ds{=} &
\ds{\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}{n \choose k}{1 + \color{red}{\pars{-1}^{k}} \over 2}}
& \ds{=} &
\ds{2^{n - 1}}
\\[5mm]
\ds{S_{2}} & \ds{\equiv} &
\ds{\sum_{k = 0}^{\left\lfloor \pars{n - 1}/\pars{2k}\right\rfloor}
{n \choose 2k + 1}}
& \ds{=} &
\ds{\sum_{k = 0}^{\infty}{n \choose k}{1 - \color{red}{\pars{-1}^{k}} \over 2}}
& \ds{=} &
\ds{2^{n - 1}}
\end{array}\right.
\end{align}
The $\ds{\color{red}{\tt red\ factors}}$ don't yield any contribution when $\ds{\underline{\underline{n > 0}}}$.